# What happens if I assign a value before defining its variable? (ALGOL scope ruleset)

Tags: language-agnostic, scope, programming-languages

In languages with scope rules like in ALGOL it is allowed to assign a value to a variable before it is defining, i.e. the declaration is valid within its entire {block}. The ALGOL scope ruleset is used, for instance, in Pascal and in Java (namespace and method visibility).

The following example will print `42`.

```
print i;
int i = 42;
```

But what happens in the following code snippet?

```
i = 21;
print i;
int i = 42;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question cannot be answered from a language-agnostic perspective. It is very likely that this cannot even be answered in a language-specific, compiler-agnostic perspective.  The behavior will be determined by the compiler itself.

An example [Algol-68 compiler](https://files.nyu.edu/at570/public/compiler.html) will create the symbol for i, then iterate line-by line through a particular block, so will print 21.

Other compilers may handle this differently, resulting in an error, or 42, but will most likely behave similar to the example above.

Comment: For Algol 68, the result must be that 21 is printed; the resolution of the identifier 'i' is not ambiguous.  For Algol 60, the matter cannot arise, since declarations always precede statements (and there is no syntax for initialization)